# How override woocommerce view-order template?

Tags: templates, woocommerce

This page: /my-account/view-order/132616/

... is associated with the view-order.php template file under the my account section. I am able to edit this by going directly into the woocommerce plugin dir, but copying the file into /my-child-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/view-order.php does not have any effect. I am able to edit the orders.php template in this manner, but not this one. I haven't been able to find any answers online to this one: why some of these template files can be copied / overwritten and some cannot be? Also, there appears to be limited scope on applying a hook to manipulate the content on this page. What I want to do, is turn the product names listed here into links back to the products in the store. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

turns out this doesn't satisfy my need since the content I'm trying to manipulate is in the woocommerce_view_order do_action. Now I'm on the hunt for a filter hook.